# What is the correct way to use `Mixin` in `React` ES6

Tags: reactjs, firebase, mixins, es6-class, reactfire

**In ES5:**

```
var TodoApp = React.createClass({
  mixins: [ReactFireMixin], //working fine
  ...
});
```

**In ES6:** (created using [react cli](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/07/22/create-apps-with-no-configuration.html) )

```
class TodoApp extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }
    mixins= [ReactFireMixin] //not working
    ...
}
```

what is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[react-mixin](https://github.com/brigand/react-mixin) solved my problem

**CODE:**

```
class TodoApp extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }        
    ...
}
reactMixin(TodoApp .prototype, ReactFireMixin);
```

Answer (score 1):

Mixins are deprecated and are not supported by ES6 classes.  See https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/07/13/mixins-considered-harmful.html.  I used mixins extensively on a project a few years back and it ended up being super-hard to maintain.  Use composition instead.

Comment: then how to use reactfire?

Comment: @InzamamMalik seems to be an ongoing open issue on their github https://github.com/firebase/reactfire/issues/38#issuecomment-192963227